# Redirecting 301 using express and node.js. GET not being called

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, express, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to do a simple a 301 redirection. My code for that looks something like this:

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
  console.log(req.get('host')+req.originalUrl);
  if(req.get('host')+req.originalUrl == "facebook.com:3000/"){
    res.redirect(301,'https://youtube.com');
  } else {
    res.redirect(301,'https://google.com');
  }
});
```

So I what did was edited my host file so that facebook.com was linked to localhost (127.0.0.1)
Problem is my `app.get()` isn't being called except for a couple of times( usually when I don't look at **app.js** file for a while then use it again). After those times, it will always redirect to the same website even if I edit the file for it redirect to other websites.  Here is some relevant code in addition to this:

```
app.locals.cacheBuster = Date.now();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || argv.p || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.compress());
app.use(express.favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public/img/favicon.ico')));
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.session({
  secret: 'your secret code',
  store: new MongoStore({
    db: mongoose.connection.db,
    auto_reconnect: true
  })
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals({
    user: req.user,
    cookies: req.cookies,
    pullup: { // global client-side JS object
      baseUrl: req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host')
    }
  });

  if (!_.isObject(req.session.flash) || !Object.keys(req.session.flash).length) {
    req.session.windowscrolly = 0;
  }
  if (req.body.windowscrolly) req.session.windowscrolly = req.body.windowscrolly;
  res.locals.windowscrolly = req.session.windowscrolly;
  res.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com http://sysinct.herokuapp.com; frame-src 'self' https://gitter.im;");
  res.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
  next();
});

app.use(flash());

app.use(less({ src: __dirname + '/public', compress: true }));

app.use(app.router);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), { maxAge: week }));

app.use(function(req, res) {
  res.render('404', { status: 404 });
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  console.error("req: "+req +"\nerror:"+err.stack);
  res.statusCode = 500;
  res.render('error',{error:err});
});

app.locals.timeago = timeago;
```

...eventually,

```
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("✔ Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.get('port'), app.settings.env);
});
```

I've tried inserting my app.get function into various places around this chunk of code (I'm aware I don't put `app.get()` in this example right now because I don't know where to put it) because I read that the order that it has with `app.use(app.router)` and other middleware matters, but I've had no luck finding out why the `app.get()` isn't called.

1. I'd like to know why `app.get()` isn't being called
2. If my way of redirecting is right. 
   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 301 redirects, the chrome browser stores information of the 301 redirect in the cache(so that the server can load data faster in the future). So my app.get wasn't being called because the cache was serving a localized version of the web page instead of requesting from the server again. 
To make it work, clear the cache in the setting (where browsing history is). Then, it will redirect by requesting to web server accordingly and app.get() will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting at the top:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

?

I know before used to work something like

`var bodyParser = require('express.bodyParser()');`

but no longer, now is separated from express and I am seeing you have a few modules like that, couldnt be that?

Comment: Yes I set the express at the top. Could you elaborate on your second comment? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Got it. Not an express problem but a browser cache thing.